# Ограничение операций в Razor View

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc

Есть необходимость предоставлять людям доступ по FTP к папке с сайтом. Очень не хотелось бы, чтобы они вытащили dll'ки из папки bin.

Доступ по фтп легко ограничивается, но никто не мешает пользователю, скажем, изменить View и, используя функции того же `System.IO` скопировать библиотеку в доступное ему место. Ну или каким-либо другим способом вытащить dll. Как ограничить операции в `View`'ах?

Answer (score 1):

Я предполагаю, что вам нужно выставить права на  запись на каждую дерикторию и/или файл в соответствие с вашей политикой изменений, запретив изменения для пользователей, не являющихся администраторами или NETWORK_SERVICE.

Другой вариант - прекомпилировать view'хи (например, используя дополнение Razor Generator для MSVS) и не хранить их на жёстком диске.

Думаю, лучше использовать оба метода сразу.